# chacha20-poly1305 in PHP with OpenSSL

Tags: php, openssl, cryptography, php-openssl

I'm running PHP 7.2.8. According to `openssl_get_cipher_methods` chacha20-poly1305 is a supported algorithm:

```
echo in_array('chacha20-poly1305', openssl_get_cipher_methods()) ? 'yes' : 'no';
```

That outputs "yes".

So I tried to use `chacha20-poly1305`:

```
$plaintext = 'zzzzzz';
$key = str_repeat('k', 32);
$nonce = str_repeat('n', 12);
$aad = '';

$r = openssl_encrypt(
    $plaintext,
    'chacha20-poly1305',
    $key,
    OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,
    $nonce,
    $newtag,
    $aad
);

echo bin2hex($r);
```

That output a PHP warning:

> Warning: openssl_encrypt(): The authenticated tag cannot be provided for cipher that doesn not support AEAD

`$r` was `f4854428b8a8`.

I was able to get the same output for `r` with `chacha20` (ie. no `poly1305` by doing this):

```
$r = openssl_encrypt(
    $plaintext,
    'chacha20',
    $key,
    OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,
    "\1\0\0\0" . $nonce
);
```

The fact that the output is the same means that the Poly1305 authentication code is neither being appended or prepended to the ciphertext.

My question is...  how do I get the Poly1305 authentication code using OpenSSL in PHP?

Also, I'm aware that libsodium provides chacha20-poly1305 support but I am, none-the-less, still curious as to how it's supposed to work with OpenSSL.

Comment: If I recall correctly, ChaCha20/Poly1305 is more like an internal cipher used by OpenSSL in TLS. It is not general purpose for use in [`EVP_*`](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption) interfaces, `openssl enc` or `openssl dec`. In fact I don't believe the OpenSSL subcommands (`enc` and `dec`) support authenticated encryption modes because there's no way to retrieve them or specify them. Things may have changed since OpenSSL 1.1.0, however.

Comment: @jww - `enc` and `dec` support aes-128-gcm, etc, but I think that (well and aes-192-gcm and aes-256-gcm) and chacha20-poly1305 are the only AEAD algorithms OpenSSL supports. And chacha20-poly1305 does seem to be behaving differently, so you're comment about it being internal only could very well be true

Comment: *"enc and dec support aes-128-gcm"* - Actually, it does not (or it did not in the past). Its a bug that the subcommands accept the ciphers. See [v1.0.1g command line gcm error](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mailing.openssl.users/hGggWxfrZbA/Tc-VHdJDqfwJ) on the OpenSSL mailing list; and [OpenSSL RT Issue 3354](http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/openssl-org-3354-PATCH-doc-update-for-enc-utility-enc-does-not-handle-authenticated-encryption-modes-td50142.html). Sorry to split hairs.

Comment: Ping @mattcaswell. Matt is one of the OpenSSL devs who patrols Stack Overflow on occasion. He can probably tell you exactly what is happening without looking at the sources.

Comment: @jww - PHP's OpenSSL bindings do support aes-128-gcm as evidenced by https://pastebin.com/kbqX7mAq . I got the output without error on PHP 7.2.8. It's just chacha20-poly1305 that gives that error (well at least amongst aes-128-gcm, aes-256-gcm and chacha20-poly1305)

Comment: With PHP 7.4, I do not get any warning from `openssl_encrypt()`, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

PHP 8.2 [added support for AEAD for chacha20-poly1305](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration82.new-features.php#migration82.new-features.openssl).

I tested it with the following code, which is the same code shown in the question, except it also prints the AEAD tag.

```php
<?php

$plaintext = 'zzzzzz';
$key = str_repeat('k', 32);
$nonce = str_repeat('n', 12);
$aad = '';

$r = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, 'chacha20-poly1305', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $nonce, $tag, $aad);

echo bin2hex($r), "\n", bin2hex($tag), "\n";
```

The output I got is the following.

```
$ php test_chacha20.php                                                                                     
f4854428b8a8
0a0f1fab235b365765364a61e1bb68ff
```

No warning was printed.

Replacing `'chacha20-poly1305'` with `'chacha20'` in that code will cause the following output to be returned.

```
$ php test_chacha20.php
PHP Warning:  openssl_encrypt(): IV passed is only 12 bytes long, cipher expects an IV of precisely 16 bytes, padding with \0 in test_chacha20.php on line 8
b0089b7135bd
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with OpenSSL is still unsolved (Nov. 2020) so if you need to use
ChaCha20-Poly1305 authenticated encryption with PHP I recommend the library from
Leigh (https://github.com/lt/PHP-AEAD-ChaCha20-Poly1305) that can be implemented
very easy.

The auth-tag ($tag) is appended to the ciphertext and needs to get separated before
start the decryption.

Just a note as I'm testing the same functionality with OpenJDK 11 (Java): both functions produce the same ciphertext but **different** auth-tags, so they are not usable in a cross-platform environment.

output:

```
ChaCha20-Poly1305 encryption with leigh/aead-chacha20-poly1305
tag (16 bytes long, Base64): FK11WpqxhDuJytSgHN86tQ==
ciphertext (Base64):         1rXNtbeGF9KsMZXgPjszIeJ0Ze5ua+Uh5Aexu1ngaH4XoeldG71DwuDEAA==
decrypt: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

the code (**security warning: never use a static key or nonce in production**):

```
<?php
# make sure that you used Composer to get "leigh/aead-chacha20-poly1305"
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

// ### never use static key & nonce in production, this is for testing only ###
$key = '12345678901234567890123456789012'; // 32 bytes
$nonce = '123456789012'; // 12 bytes
$plaintext = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
$aad = '';

echo 'ChaCha20-Poly1305 encryption with leigh/aead-chacha20-poly1305' . PHP_EOL;
list($ciphertext, $tag) = \ChaCha20Poly1305\encrypt($key, $nonce, $aad, $plaintext);
echo 'tag (16 bytes long, Base64): ' . base64_encode($tag) . PHP_EOL;
echo 'ciphertext (Base64):         ' . base64_encode($ciphertext) . PHP_EOL;
$decrypt = \ChaCha20Poly1305\decrypt($key, $nonce, $aad, $ciphertext, $tag);
echo 'decrypt: ' . $decrypt . PHP_EOL;
?>
```